# Confirmation box with yes and No option, on drop down list's selected index change

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using Following code to show a confirmation box.

```
protected void cmbPayerBucketMain_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    ClientScriptManager CSM = Page.ClientScript;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hiddenF1.Value) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(hiddenF2.Value))
    {
          CSM.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Confirm", "show();", true);
    }

   //Some Code       
}
```

And function show() as follows

```
function show()
        (
            if(confirm('Chnages you made will be lost. Do you want to continue?'))
            { return true; }
             else
             { return false;
              }

              return 

        )
```

But irrespective of what option i have selected from confirmation box, it is executing the whole code. And after executing the whole event code it pops up msg box. How can I restrict the combo box for waiting for the response of confirmation box and execute the event code only when user select 'ok' (or 'yes' also suggest me the way to change the text of buttons in confirmation box. I want to make this OK to YES and CANCEL to NO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the text of the buttons in the confirm dialog. They're built into the browser.

If you want more control over the dialog box use the [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) from jQuery UI, but it won't allow you to block the UI thread for input i.e. you can't do something as simple as `confirm(...)` and get the result on the next line. I suggest you read some the documentation on how to process the result of the user's interaction with the dialog. In particular, see [this example](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) from the docs. I'll try to adapt some a simple example here:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Yes": function() {
        // whatever you want to run when user clicks 'yes'.
        ...
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      },
      "No": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
<div id="dialog-confirm">
   ...
</div>
```

Just a minor point... if you choose to stick with the built-in confirm dialog, you can simplify your code as

```
function show() {
    return confirm('Chnages you made will be lost. Do you want to continue?');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's executing all the code in this function because it's not a function. You are using parens `()` instead of curly braces `{}`. Also the method p.s.w.g. suggest for return value is better.

```js
function show() { 
    return confirm('Changes you made will be lost. Do you want to continue?');
} // use curly braces, not parens here
```

Comment: In the event where I am registering script. How can I receive the value of confirmation box (weather clicked OK or Cancel) @ThinkingStiff

Comment: @Pramod Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134351/executing-javascript-function-in-code-behind-how-to-get-the-return-value-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Please trythe below code for confirm box customization.

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.confirm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            function ShowConfirm(Title, Message, OkBtnCaption, CancelBtnCaption, ButtonID) {
                var elem = $(this).closest('.item');               

                $.confirm({
                    'title': Title,
                    'message': Message,
                    'buttons': {
                        OkBtnCaption: {
                            'class': 'blue',
                            'action': function () { $('#' + ButtonID).click(); },
                            'id': 'okBtn'
                        },
                        CancelBtnCaption: {
                            'class': 'gray',
                            'action': function () { },
                            'id': 'cancelBtn'
                        }
                   }
                });
                return false;
            }   
      </script>
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks,
Siva